# Show username for logged users and sign up/login links for others

Tags: php, html

I really need help for my login script. I want to show some PHP codes to show username for logged-in users else for others show only login/signup link.

Codes given below.

```
/*---Logged in user's homepage---*/


<?PHP

require_once('../lib/connections/db.php');

include('../lib/functions/functions.php');

checkLogin('2');

$getuser = getUserRecords($_SESSION['user_id']);

?>

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<title><?=$getuser[0]['username'];?>'s Profile Page | HDS Web</title>

<?php include('../headother.php'); ?>

<div style="background:#FFFFFF; padding-bottom:150px; padding-top:15px;">


/*----User's photo and details section goes below----*/


<div style="float:left; width:600px;">  

<p>
Welcome <?php if(empty($getuser[0]['first_name']) || empty($getuser[0]['last_name'])){echo $getuser[0]['username'];} else {echo $getuser[0]['first_name']." ".$getuser[0]['last_name'];} ?></p>                       

 <? displayUserImg($getuser[0]['id']); ?>

</div>


/*---User's navigation menu section goes below---*/


<div style="float:right; width:200px;"> 

    <a href="index.php">Home</a> | <? if (!empty($getuser[0]['thumb_path'])){echo "<a href='manage_photo.php'>Manage My Photo</a> | ";} else {echo "<a href='upload_photo.php'>Upload Photo</a> | ";} ?>

<a href="change_pass.php">change password</a> | 

<a href="edit_profile.php">Edit Profile</a> 

| <a href="log_off.php?action=logoff">sign out</a></div></td>


    </div>
    <?php include('../footer.php');?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems you're already showing the `first_name` / `last_name` near "Welcome" line. What's the problem here?

Comment: Problem is that,, i want to show login / signup link together for other people who are not logged in my website. but i can't do this.... i mean using 'if' and 'else' function... when use gets logged in then get to see name or username and else only login link... please make it possible

Comment: Not enough information to help. What are the possible outputs of `getUserRecords()` (e.g. what if user cannot be found)?

Comment: which type of info do u need.... You don't need to do more.. just give any option to show login link in place of username if not logged in... that's it..

Comment: You have to determine whether a logged in user is returned from function first. Alternatively, you can use `$_SESSION['user_id']`, but this can lead to false positive.

Comment: ok, can you suggest me any free login script which provide this feature.... or give me your email and i send that script to understand it and make a right code... please

Comment: this is simple logic; you **should** do it on your own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show name for logged-in users and signup link for others?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726686/how-to-show-name-for-logged-in-users-and-signup-link-for-others)

Comment: Oh dear - after all the edit work you created on the first question, then not responding to the advice I gave you, you've now deliberately duplicated the question, six hours later?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  // detected a valid user
  ?>
  <p>Welcome <?php if(empty($getuser[0]['first_name']) || empty($getuser[0]['last_name'])){echo $getuser[0]['username'];} else {echo $getuser[0]['first_name']." ".$getuser[0]['last_name'];} ?></p>
  <?php                  
  displayUserImg($getuser[0]['id']);
} else {
  // didn't login, show login link
  echo '<p><a href="login.php">Login Link</a></p>';
}
```

Mentioned in comment, checking `$_SESSION['user_id']` does not guarantee accurate result, as the function may not return a user object when the `user_id` is not found in database. It is better to determine from the return value of `getUserRecords()`.

Side Notes:

- Where is your `DOCTYPE` ?
- Your HTML maybe invalid, without closing `<head>` and opening `<body>` tags (well, it may be contained in your included files. Who knows?)
- stop using inline CSS
- recommend not to use `<?` . Use `<?php` instead

Comment: ok, I'll mind these issues,, I'm checking this code example, and will get back to u..